# Are there different string nan values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, nan

I have a dataframe with two columns for which I compare the values. The rows for these different values and the values themselves are saved in a new dataframe.

Dataframe before comparing:

| other columns | value_a | value_b | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 12 | 12 | ... |
| ... | 1.3 | 1.6 | ... |
| ... | abc | def | ... |

Dataframe after comparing:

| other columns | value_a | value_b | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... | 1.3 | 1.6 | ... |
| ... | abc | def | ... |

The problem is that I also get the following lines:

| other columns | value_a | value_b | other columns |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ... |  |  | ... |
| ... |  |  | ... |

Empty cells are compared with each other and reported as non-matching.

Now I have created a set for each of the columns value_a and value_b to see which values occur in the columns. I used the following code for this:

`df2['non-numeric_a'] = df['value_a'].mask(df['value_a'].notna())`

`df2['non-numeric_b'] = df['value_b'].mask(df['value_b'].notna())`

Then I looked at the columns as a set, because I wanted to see the unique values that occur for each column:
`print(set( df2['non-numeric_a']))`
`print(set( df2['non-numeric_b']))`

My output for the sets was:
`{nan}`
and
`{nan, nan, nan, ..., nan}`

Comment: @mozway it's not as straight-forward as that.  The way a set works if you have a nan singleton, they will collapse to one element but if they're individual objects (such as created by e.g. numpy) they can be repeated.

Comment: @MarkRansom it's true, it's more tricky (e.g. `{np.nan, np.nan}` -> `{nan}`)? But I believe OP might want a practical solution to get a single NaN (or none) in the set

Comment: My actual intention is to see what values are stored in the empty cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A NaN is not equal to itself, thus `set([float('nan'), float('nan')])` -> `{nan, nan}`

Rather `dropna` before converting to `set`:

```
set(df2['non-numeric_b'].dropna()))
```

Or:

```
set(df2['non-numeric_b'].unique())
```

Example:

```
s= pd.Series([float('nan'), float('nan'), 1, 1, 2, 3])

set(s)
# {nan, nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}

set(s.dropna())
# {1.0, 2.0, 3.0}

set(s.unique())
# {nan, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}
```

Comment: But if I convert the column ``df2['non-numeric_a']`` into a set then I only get one ``nan`` as output, although there are also several nan values in the column.

Comment: @di1a as Mark pointed out in comments, it depends how the NaN was created. Using `set(s.unique())` should work in all cases.

Comment: I did it with the ``pd.Series`` and got ``[nan]`` as output for both columns. How to interpret ``nan``? If I have a field with ``" "`` (one space) and a field ``"        "`` (several spaces), am I talking about the same ``nan`` values in both cases?

Comment: `" "` and `"   "` are definitely not NaNs

Comment: I thought maybe an empty string is also stored as nan. Then I can assume here that I do not have an empty string but nan? In other words, the empty cells that don't match can be both nan values or empty strings that have different amounts of spaces?

Comment: The best might be to remove the empty strings and replace them by real NaNs

Comment: And what is the best way to do this if I have empty strings with different numbers of empty characters?

Comment: Assuming you have columns of strings: `df = df.replace(r'\s+', np.nan, regex=True)`

Comment: My column is filled with different data types. Both string and numeric data types occur.

Comment: It's hard to tell without a clear reproducible example. Please provide one if you have further issues

Comment: It worked with ``df.replace(r'^\s*$', np.nan, regex=True)``.